# PHP: How to get an associative array from this XML?

Tags: php, xml, arrays

This is my code so far... needless to say, it's not working :(

```
$feed = <<< THEXML

<programs>
<program>
<date>2009-04-16</date>
<start_time>17:00</start_time>
<leadtext>hello hello!
</leadtext>
<name>Program 1</name>
<b-line>Comedy</b-line>
<synopsis>Funny stuff
</synopsis>
<url>http://www.domain.tld/program_name</url>
</program>
<programs>
THEXML;


$xml  = (array) simplexml_load_string($feed);

print_r($xml);exit;
```

Would appreciate any help, have been around the php.net site for hours now and feeling braindead.

Please note that in the example xml above there is just one

```
 <program>...</program>
```

tag, but in reality I have one or more of them that I need to use.
For example

```
 <programs>
 <program>...</program>
 <program>...</program>
 <program>...</program>
 </programs>
```

I figured if I can get one to work then I can loop it, but just thought I would explain what I am going for here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($xml);`? What is keeping you from looping through it?

Comment: The XML you posted, also, is not valid XML.

Comment: I am getting errors before it reaches the print_r statement. Unfortunately thats the XML I have to work with... I can add something in the beginning or the end... but the middle rest must be untouched.

Comment: Ok, warnings.. not errors and the output at the bottom is: Array ( [0] => ) Will post the warnings in a sec

Comment: Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: Entity: line 17: parser error : Premature end of data in tag programs line 17 in C:\wamp\www\MTG\test_array2.php on line 26 ****** Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: &lt;programs&gt; in C:\wamp\www\MTG\test_array2.php on line 2

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18765/discussion-between-rob-and-ryan)

Comment: Oops, just saw your chat comment, sorry I was paying attention below and didnt see you post on top!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the provider gives you valid XML, then you just have to iterate through the programs and use any information you need off it, like so:

```
<?php
foreach ( $xml as $node ) {
    echo $node->synopsis;
    //or whatever property you want to access on the SimpleXMLElement Object
}
```

Since you don't have correct XML (being an unclosed `<programs>` tag, then you might want to modify your script to correct that error like so:

```
$feed = preg_replace('/<programs>$/', '</programs>', trim($feed));
```

Comment: The XML will be in the exact same format as I posted it, I can add something in the beginning or the end, but cannot touch the xml that comes in.

Comment: Then it's not valid XML, so using an XML parser is not the way to go, specially if you can't correct the errors that are being thrown.

Comment: Well, start by correcting the XML by doing what @StRuPs suggests, probably doing something like: `$xml = preg_replace('/<programs>$/, '</programs>', trim($xml));` and then feeding the results through simple_xml_load_string();

Comment: Yep, that gives me some output...Thanks! I think I can work with the output I am getting now :)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the end closing tag.

```
$feed = <<< THEXML

<programs>
<program>
<date>2009-04-16</date>
<start_time>17:00</start_time>
<leadtext>hello hello!
</leadtext>
<name>Program 1</name>
<b-line>Comedy</b-line>
<synopsis>Funny stuff
</synopsis>
<url>http://www.domain.tld/program_name</url>
</program>
</programs> // <========= here
THEXML;
```

Comment: I am not good with XML, I see you pointing, but how should it look then? It starts with programs and ends with /programs... what's missing?

Comment: That's what gave you the previous error. To transform it into an array, you must iteratively visit every node and its children. I'll grab some code for you. ;)

Comment: I kind of see what you mean, I took out the "programS" tags and I got an array...  the problem is I may get 1 "program" (no S) or many "program" tags enclosed in a "programS" tag :( OK,Will wait for your response.

Comment: I tried using DOMDocument but it did not work. There's this extension Tidy, but the output is not **that** correct.

Get it here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php
And try this:
`// Config
$config = array(
 'indent'     => true,
 'input-xml'  => true,
 'output-xml' => true,
 'wrap'       => false
);

// Tidy
$tidy = new tidy();
$tidy->parseString($feed, $config, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();
print_r($tidy);`

Comment: Don't worry about it, I think I can work with Rob's solution as I am getting some output and no errors. Upvoted you, Thanks again.